# Updated CSS in pub/static doesn't reflect in browser!

Tags: magento2.3, css, cache

Recently I got an odd issue regarding the CSS changing.
Here is the problem:

I change the CSS in the theme folder, delete the file in the pub/static. I do static content deploy via SSH and cache flush and I can see that the CSS file is generated in the pub/static folder and IT IS UPDATED THERE. This is something I always did and it used to work.

Also, I can confirm that the CSS is updated via the direct link in the Browser's **view source code** and in the **Source tab of the Inspect window**. It means the CSS is loaded from the pub/static and I can see it is updated.

THE FUNNY AND FRUSTRATING thing is that, though the CSS file is updated and loading in the browser **I cannot see any changes in the frontend**!
I cleared the browser cache, cookies, and data. I tested it on Chrome, Chrome Incognito, and Firefox. No changes in the frontend I can see!

I'm going to be crazy about this! How is it possible?

Recently I moved the store to another server with the LiteSpeed cache but the only difference is that on my previous server, I had LiteMage Cache + LiteSpeech, in the new server the LiteMage isn't supported. I don't know if it caused the issue.

**I'm using Magento 2.3.5-p1**

**Linux Server**

**PHP Version 7.3.33**

**The Full Page Cache is on also**.

Please give your thoughts and advice if you had any and I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you removed your cache folders?

Comment: _What_ did you actually change in the stylesheet...? I doubt that the style rules you've applied/added/removed/changed(?) are applicable to the element you are expecting this particular changes on. If the stylesheet is loaded and you can not see your change in the browsers dev tools (it's not mentioned whether you've checked on that) this simply means that your style is just not applicable - or, if you can see it there it's probably striked through, hence overruled by another style...

Comment: @ZahidH Yes, I did remove the cache folder. Nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The CSS rules are ok. I checked my style rules in dev tools before adding them to the CSS file. But it is not working via the updated CSS file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the issue for a long time, I managed to resolve the issue! I decided to rename the CSS file and remove the old one in the pub/static, and do static content deploy!

The CSS renamed file is now reflected on the browser. It seems there was a cache issue regarding the file name!

Anyhow, Thank you so much for your help and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have issues once in a while with caching on various levels. What was working for me, was toggling the 'Merge CSS Files' setting from the Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> CSS Settings, from current value to the opposite, clean the cache on all layers, and then toggle the setting back, and clean the cache again.